# How to get html element tag/text when clicked in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a context menu where I want to use certain method it finds `p`/`div`, so right now I'm just logging so that to see if I find the proper element when I click.

`HTML`

```
<div>Hello I'm div</div>

<p>I'm para <span>I'm span inside para</span></p>
```

code

```
    var paraElm = $target.closest("p")
       if(paraElm){
          console.log("i have selected the element is para",paraElm)
         }
```

it gives me an array in output

`log` for para

```
i have selected the element is para,
n.fn.init [p.locked.sender, prevObject: n.fn.init(1),context: p.locked.sender]
0: p.locked.sender
context: p.locked.sender
length: 1
```

`log` for span inside para

```
i have selected the element is para,
n.fn.init [p.locked.sender, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: span.selected]
0: p.locked.sender
context: span.selected
length: 1
```

when I clicked on `span`, it shouldn't log even if it's inside `p` tag

UPDATE#1:
So I made some changes, used a condition to remove won’t log for `span` tag, just in JSFiddle it's not working as intended, but works as i expected it to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('click', function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);

    var getElm = $target.closest('p');

    if (getElm.context.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'span') {
      console.log("I got the element", getElm);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello I'm div</div>

<p>I'm para <span>I'm span inside para</span></p>
```

Comment: Your title doesn't make any sense, nor does the body. You're looking at properties other than the selected element and complaining about what they are. Who cares what the `context` property is? The `paraElem` is a paragraph element. That's all you should care about.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah ik the question doesn't make much sense as compare to the body I realized that but didn't get time, yeah afterwards I was able to understand it, the reason was to when I click on span I didn't it to log even if it's inside the p tag that's why I was focused on that instead of understanding what content I was getting.

Will soon update the question properly, thank you for understanding my effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes, used a condition to remove won’t log for span tag, but works as I expected it to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('click', function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);

    var getElm = $target.closest('p,div');

    if (getElm && getElm.length) {
      console.log("I got the element", getElm[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello I'm div</div>

<p>I'm para <span>I'm span inside para</span></p>

   <p>I'm para 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// i hope this solve your issue
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span').addClass('span');
  $('body').on('click', function(event) {
      editTask(event.target);
  });
});

function editTask(node) {

    if(!($(node).hasClass('span'))){
  var closest_element = $(node).text();
  console.log(closest_element);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello I'm div</div>

<p>I'm para <span>I'm span inside para</span></p>
```

Comment: Okay it does help, but I don't want to log, when I click on <span> tag and what exactly is `node` doing here? I just wanted to know so that I can see a way to filter out <span>

Comment: check now i hop now solve your issue proper